# saving data in localStorage with react-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage, react-big-calendar

I'm implementing react-big-calendar in my toy project, and I want the events in the calendar to stay even after refreshing the page. I was planning to save the events in localStorage and then retrieve them back. However, even after saving the events in localStorage, all the events are gone after page is rendered.

```
export default function Calendar() {
  const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

  const [events, setEvents] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const handleSelectSlot = useCallback(
    ({ start, end }) => {
      const title = window.prompt("create an event");
      if (title) {
        setEvents((prev) => [...prev, { start, end, title }]);
      }
    },
    [setEvents]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(events));
  }, [events]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (events.length) {
      localStorage.getItem("events" || "[]");
    }
  }, []);

  const onClickRemoveEvent = (event: any) => {
    const newEvents = events.filter((el) => el.start !== event.start);
    setEvents([...newEvents, events]);
  };

  const { defaultDate, scrollToTime } = useMemo(
    () => ({
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      scrollToTime: new Date(2000, 1, 1, 6),
    }),
    []
  );

  const eventStyleGetter = (event: any) => {
    console.log("eventGetter:", event.hexColor);
    // const backgroundColor = "#" + event.hexColor;
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: "beige",
      borderRadius: "0px",
      opacity: 0.8,
      color: "black",
      border: "0px",
      display: "block",
    };
    return {
      style,
    };
  };

  return (
    <>
      <S.Wrapper>
        <S.ScheduleCalendar
          localizer={localizer}
          events={events}
          selectable={true}
          views={["month", "week", "day"]}
          defaultDate={defaultDate}
          onSelectSlot={handleSelectSlot}
          onSelectEvent={onClickRemoveEvent}
          scrollToTime={scrollToTime}
          eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
        />
      </S.Wrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there a way I could save the events data?

Answer (score 0):

You can store and retrieve `events` data in `localStorage`, but...

You have to remember that `localStorage` does not preserve data types, meaning you must manually convert all event `start` and `end` dates back to JS `Date` objects prior to putting them in your `events` prop. See Big Calendar's documentation on [Understanding Dates](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/guides-understanding-dates--page)